# ImportError: No module named request when importing BeakerX into Jupyter

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, beaker

I am trying to import beakerx into my jupyter environment like so:

```
from beakerx import *
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-4c368a35c7cf> in <module>()
----> 1 from beakerx import *

/Users/vivaksoni1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beakerx/__init__.py in <module>()
     13 # limitations under the License.
     14 
---> 15 from .runtime import BeakerX
     16 from .plot import *
     17 from .easyform import *

/Users/vivaksoni1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beakerx/runtime.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 import os, json, pandas, numpy
---> 18 import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse, IPython, datetime, calendar, math, traceback, time
     19 from traitlets import Unicode
     20 

ImportError: No module named request
```

I am not sure what this error means? Also, it seems to be looking into python2.7 directories even though this is a python 3 script? I installed beakerx using: `pip3 install beakerx` and can see the files in the right folder within the right folder:

```
 anaconda3/pkgs/beakerx-0.12.2-py36_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/beakerx
```

This seems to be how every other module is stored but I cannot get it working for some reason. Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to be running it with a python2.7 interpreter. You should specify you want to use python 3 while making your virtualenv

Comment: I am getting all sorts of issues when trying to specify a python 3 environment when creating a virtualenv (e.g. using the command: (venv) bash$ virtualenv -p /path/to/python3  v3
Running virtualenv with interpreter /path/to/python3
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/python3
  Reason: image not found